# Rails Iterating over object in has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, mongoid

I have two models as:

> Family --> has_many :persons
>
> Person --> belongs_to :family

I want to query `Family' and again query the` Persons` from the result. For ex

```
@families=Family.all
@families=@families.where(........#queries.......)
@results=[]
@families.each do |family|
   @persons=family.persons
   @persons=@persons.where(.........#queries.........)
   @results << @persons
end
@results.flatten!               #because this will be an array of arrays.
```

At the end I just want to get all the **persons** which satisfy both the `Family` and the `Person` queries.

But this doesn't work for both the queries. It either works for the `Person` or for the `Family` but not both.

What is wrong here?

I'm following the **[111-advanced-search-form-revised](https://github.com/railscasts/111-advanced-search-form-revised/blob/master/store-after/app/models/search.rb)** railscast but for searching in has_many relationship.

I'm using Mongoid with Rails 3.

**EDIT**: what I have written seems to be correct. Is there another, more elegant, way to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@families = Family.where(........#queries.......)
@results = []
@families.each do |family|
   @persons = family.persons.where(.........#queries.........)
   @results = @result.concat(@persons)
end
```

Notice: you don't need `@results.flatten!`, since `@result.concat(@persons)` merges the arrays.

EDIT:

You can also do this, same result as the nice query of @Finbarr:

```
@persons = Person.where({ ***your query***, :family_id.in => Family.where({ *** query***}).pluck(:id)})
```

Comment: I get `NoMethodError: undefined method \`pluck' for #<Array:0x007fd36e5f17e0>` in mongoid.

Answer (score 0):

If all you actually want is the Persons, I'd suggest something like this:

```
Person.where(.....#queries.....).where("family_id IN (SELECT id FROM families WHERE <family queries>)")
```

This will get all your persons in 1 query.

Comment: That's a rails nice way :)

Comment: But the OP says "I'm using Mongoid with Rails 3." and Mongoid won't have a clue what to do with that SQL.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice the Mongoid part. In that case my answer is irrelevant.